# Difference between employ and deploy

Tags: vocabulary

could someone explain why the word "employ" couldn't be the answer to this blank? since one of its meanings is: [v] to use sth such as a skill, method, etc. for a particular purpose.

As the technology develops and the market widens, the company intends to ......(deploy, employ) more Sea Combines, including in its home country, India.

- “Sea Combine,” an automated catamaran that simultaneously harvests and replants seaweed in the ocean.

Answer: deploy

Source: CNN Business

Comment: Employ means -**to use something** , deploy-**to use something (especially in a useful and successful way)** . Hence,Here, the company wants to **deploy** more sea combines.....

Comment: ***Employ*** usually means to make use of the resources yourself. ***Deploy*** more often means to *distribute* resources to be used by others under your direction / on pursuit of your objective.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that the company plans to *employ* some equipment suggests that it is already available, and they're just going to make use of it. Saying that the company plans to *deploy* the equipment, on the other hand, means that they are going to send it to relevant locations, set it up, and *then* use it.

Using "employ" in this sentence also reads awkwardly to me, because it has a more common meaning of "hire someone to do a job", so "employing Sea Combines" makes it sound like the Sea Combines are people (or maybe intelligent robots) being given a contract.

Answer (score 2):

The verb **deploy** means to send resources (e.g. troops or equipment) to a place so that the resources can be put to use there, whereas **employ** means simply to use, i.e. as a tool.

It would be possible to speak of the automated catamaran as a tool to be used in the performance of a task, the harvesting and replanting of seaweed, but since the sentence mentions a place, "including in its home country, India", **deploy** would be the better-fitting choice.